# number inputs unit conversion in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Is there anything to dynamically convert cm to meters in angular?

```
<input type="number"data-ng-model="format.width" required>
```

I receive data in cm and want to display it in meters? what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Given that conversion between cm and m is a simple multiplication/division by 100, the easiest way would be to display using

```
Distance in meters: {{format.width / 100}}
```

If you were looking at more complicated conversions, then writing a filter might make sense (it depends on how often you are doing these conversions). e.g. you could write a filter called `cmToFeet`:

```
Distance in feet: {{format.width | cmToFeet }}
```

I would suggest that if you have a variable that has an implicit unit, that you make that unit part of the name.  e.g. `format.widthInCm`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple scope function which divides by 100 (as there is 100 cm in a meter) to do it:

```
$scope.format = {
    width: 0,
    widthMeters: function () {
      return $scope.format.width / 100;
    }
}
```

```
{{format.widthMeters()}} m
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/E97ArGOW9bukJoL4oscC?p=preview)